# How to make a Facebook post box in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I want to make a Facebook post box like this in Flutter.
When pressed and it will go to another page. How can I make it?

[image: Facebook post box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi :) You should use [MaterialPageRoute](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) to Navigate between pages here we go   :

*Please Up vote Yeasin Sheikh’s answer but this is the one to* ✅

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 300,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1.5,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                "what's on your mind ?",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

updated with border

```
 GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("Nav to page");
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 300,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1.5,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                "what's on your mind ?",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: you are welcome , if it is ok to make it accepted answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have a problem now. When I  pressed it pop up a keyboard bar, I just want to go to a new screen. How can I do. Is it because you use Textfield?

Comment: is something related to this question, that we could work on?

Comment: sorry i didnot notice that much, check updated answer.